# How to inject dependency with ninject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

I'm trying to inject a class's dependency into my project using Ninject, like this:

```
     private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<FinanContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    }
```

And I declared the following class to get this dependency on the constructor, like this:

```
    public UsuarioDAO(FinanContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
    }
```

However, when trying to instantiate this class, I get compilation error, because I am not passing as an argument the class that should be being injected. What do I do to make it work?

```
     public UsuarioController(UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO)
    {
        this.UsuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
    }
```

Comment: You should be using the injected dependency instead of instantiating it: `this.UsuarioDAO = usuarioDAO;`

Comment: You're right, I don't know what was going on in my head hueheu

Comment: you are not using the injected object in your constructor. It should be  **public UsuarioController(UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO)
    {
        this.UsuarioDAO = usuarioDAO;
    }** and I would suggest you to look naming conventions in programming.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)